# Dynamically building a render function in React

Tags: jquery, reactjs, rendering

I have a render function as below. I am taking an open-source library from our current site and building it into react, and it creates a colour picker (when we get it working), http://www.booneputney.com/jquery-hex-colorpicker.html Demo 1.  We wish to continue using this as it's a nice simple colour picker.

The only issue I am trying to move the dynamic building of the picker into the render() function.  I'm reasonably new to React, and I've searched high and low for an answer... but it renders the tags and so on like so in the browser.

```
undefined</div><div className = "picker-sidebar">
</div><div className = "picker-form-wrapper"><form className = "picker-form" onsubmit=
{this.submitColorChoice}><input type="text" name="selected-color" className = 
"selected-color" readonly="readonly"/><input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit" 
className = "submit"/></form></div></div>
```

Any solutions?

Thank you for your help.

```
    render() {
        let output;
        {


            for (let row = 0; row < this.state.settings.maxBlocks; row++) {
                let blocksCount = this.state.settings.size + row;
                if (row >= this.state.settings.size) {
                    blocksCount = this.state.settings.size * 2 - (row - this.state.settings.size + 2);
                }
                output += "<div className = 'picker-row'>";
                for (let block = 0; block < blocksCount; block++) {
                    let y = centerBlock - row;
                    let x = -centerBlock + (block + (this.state.settings.maxBlocks - blocksCount) / 2);
                    let radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
                    let normRadius = radius / maxRadius;
                    angle = Math.atan(y / x) * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
                    if (x >= 0) {
                        angle += 180;//compensate for right 2 quadrants
                    }
                    if (settings.colorModel === "hsv") {
                        valueLightness = 1;
                    } else {
                        valueLightness = 0.5;
                    }
                    if (normRadius === 0) {
                        angle = 0;
                    }//force angle to prevent undefined
                    output += "<div className = 'color-block' style='background-color:" + this.colorizeBlock(normRadius, angle, valueLightness) + "'></div>";
                }
                output += "</div>";
            }
            output += "</div>";
            output += '<div className = "picker-sidebar">';
            for (let row = 0; row < this.state.settings.maxBlocks; row++) {
                output += "<div className = 'color-block'></div>";
            }
            output += '</div>';
            output += '<div className = "picker-form-wrapper"><form className = "picker-form" onsubmit={this.submitColorChoice}>' +
                '<input type="text" name="selected-color" className = "selected-color" readonly="readonly"/>' +
                '<input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit" className = "submit"/>' +
                '</form></div>';
            output += "</div>";//end of hex-color-picker-wrapper
        }
        const colourPicker = <React.Fragment>{output}</React.Fragment>
        return (colourPicker)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involved using arrays and then placing the list of elements within the parent element instead of just appending the result to a string.

NOTE make sure you provide a unique key for each element or you'll get errors from React in some cases.

For clarification, use <React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment> when you do not want a wrapping div around your component.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

```
    createColorPicker() {
        let wrapper_container = []; // main wrapper
        let color_picker_container = [];
        let picker_container = [];
        let picker_side_container = [];
        let picker_bottom_container = [];
        let picker_row_container = [];
        let row;
        for (row = 0; row < this.state.settings.maxBlocks; row++) {
            
                children_blocks.push(<div key = {"row-" + row + "color-block-" + key_block}>

                </div>);
                key_block++;
            }
            picker_row_container.push(<div key = {"row-block-" + row}
                                           className = 'picker-row'> {children_blocks}</div>);
        }
        let sideColorBlock = [];
        let key_i = 1
        for (let row = 0; row < this.state.settings.maxBlocks; row++) {
            sideColorBlock.push(<div  className = 'color-block'> </div>);
            key_i++;
        }
        picker_container.push(<div key = "container-1" className = 'color-picker-container'>
            {picker_row_container}
        </div>)
        picker_side_container.push(<div key = "container-2" className = "picker-sidebar">{sideColorBlock}</div>);
        picker_bottom_container.push(
            <div key = "container-3" className = "picker-form-wrapper">
                <form className = "picker-form" onSubmit = {}>
                    <input type = "text" name = "" className = "" />
                    <input type = "submit" value = "OK" name = "submit" className = "submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>);
        wrapper_container.push(<div key = "wrapper-container" className = 'hex-color-picker-wrapper'>
            {picker_container}{picker_side_container}{picker_bottom_container}
        </div>)
        return wrapper_container;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed opening `<div>`. You can add it in the `output` declaration

**UPD**

```
 render() {
    let output; // output equals undefined here
    ...
    output += "<div className = 'picker-row'>"; // here you concatenate undefined and <div>
```

That's why browser renders `undefined</div><div className = "picker-sidebar"> ...`.
output variable should be initialized with an opening tag. There is no talk about the fragment at all and about React.

Comment: <React.Fragment> serves the same purpose, it just doesn't render in the DOM. I changed to a div just for my own sanity but just get the same output I'm afraid. Thanks for your reply and help :). Any other ideas?

Comment: @OrangeSubmarine121 if you check output variable on the first step you will get what is problem